# Différence entre pâté, tourte et tarte

Tags: sens, alimentation

Je voudrais savoir la différence entre une tarte, un pâté et une tourte. Selon mon intuition, je les définirais comme ceci :

1. Pâté : Composé de viande, poisson.
2. Tarte : Dessert
3. Tourte : La seule idée que j'ai est la comparaison avec une tourtière (gros mijoté de viande).

Si quelqu'un a les vraies définitions j'aimerais bien les connaitre pour bien utiliser les termes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. **Le paté**

Le paté est une préparation à base de viande, que l'on mange généralement sur du pain, en apéritif ([image](http://i77.servimg.com/u/f77/09/03/28/48/terrfo12.jpg))

2. **La tarte**

Une tarte n'est pas nécessairement un dessert.
Il existe des tartes salées (quiche lorraine par exemple).
Une tarte est donc définie par l'utilisation de la pâte (feuilletée, brisée, sablée...), avec un rebord [élevé et ondulé](https://img.cuisineaz.com/660x660/2013-12-20/i1097-tarte-aux-pommes-a-la-poudre-d-amandes-et-cannelle.jpg), fait dans un [plat à tarte](http://media.mathon.fr/Images/Produitsv2/Amazon/30158_0_0_-Le-Creuset-Moule-a-Tarte-Ceramique-28-Cm-Rouge.jpg).

3. **La tourte**

On remarque que la tourte est en fait un croisement entre une tarte et un hamburger :) (cf [image](https://www.atelierdeschefs.com/media/recette-d13455-tourte-a-la-ratatouille-et-au-bacon.jpg)). Il y a donc une couche de pâte dessous, puis la préparation (généralement à base de viande), puis une nouvelle couche de pâte qui referme le tout.

**Complément:**
Il existe aussi la notion de "paté en croute", et de "paté croute".

4. **Le pâté en croute**

Le pâté en croute est rectangulaire, plus haut qu'une tarte et plus fin, où 3 des cotés sont en pâte, et le haut recouvert de gelée ([image](https://files.meilleurduchef.com/mdc/photo/recette/pate-en-croute-de-noel/pate-en-croute-de-noel-640.jpg)).

5. **Le pâté croute**

Le pâté croute est un plat régional moins connu (je ne connais pas son origine), mais ressemble plutôt à un friand, ou une portion individuelle de tourte, où le pâté est entièrement recouvert de pâte ([image](https://www.regal.fr/sites/art-de-vivre/files/r59_pate-croute-morilles_ss.jpg))

Comment: Donc ce [plat](http://www.ricardocuisine.com/recettes/5548-pate-au-poulet-le-meilleur-) devrait être nommé tourte au poulet au lieu de pâté?

Comment: En effet, c'est une tourte. Peut-être que "pâté au poulet" est la garniture de la tourte ?

Comment: En Belgique (pour ne pas parler de ce quye je ne connais pas), une tarte (sucrée) peut s'appeler tarte tout en étant couverte. Il est assez commun de trouver de de la "tarte aux pommes couverte" ou de la "tarte couverte aux pommes", désignant une tarte aux pommes avec cependant une fine couche pate par dessus. La tarte peut-être sucrée ou salée, mais je n'ai pas connaissance de tourte sucrée par contre.

Comment: En Suisse Romande, 'tourte' est aussi utilisé pour désigner un gâteau, une tourte d'anniversaire par exemple

Comment: En toute rigueur un pâté sans croûte est nommé une terrine.

Answer (score 4):

Petite nuance: Le terme dépend parfois de la région.

En Acadie, on peut parler de "pâté à la viande" pour désigner ce que les Québécois appellent une "tourtière": une tarte à la viande hachée.

Les Français considèrent parfois qu'une tourtière (terme qui n'est pas utilisé en France) est simplement une tourte, mais les Québécois définissent la tourte comme n'importe quelle pâtisserie au contenu salé et servie chaude.

Au Québec, la "tarte" est exclusivement un dessert si son contenu n'est pas spécifié, car les tartes non sucrées et sans nom particulier (ex: quiche) font rarement partie de la cuisine locale.

Comment: Voir [aussi](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2091350); il semble qu'on doive nuancer pour les gens de Charlevoix, du Saguenay et au Lac !

Comment: Sans oublier le fameux [_cipaille/six-pâtes_](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8361629), le pâté à la viande qui n'est pas une tourtière !

Answer (score 0):

La tourtière est une pâtisserie très connue dans le sud-ouest. Aux pommes ou aux pruneaux et généreusement arrosée d’armagnac.

Comment: Et donc, la différence entre pâté, tourte et tarte ?